# How to load text file from Resources in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, resource-dll

I'm writing a DLL in VC++ and I need to use external text file. I have something like this right now:

```
 ifstream file;
 string line;

 file.open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\textfile.txt");
 getline(file,line);
 file.close();
```

I understand that I can have this file in Resources right?

I added my text file by going to "ResourceView" -> "Add Resource" -> "Import". I chose my text file and created custom resource type.

How can I access to this file to use similarly to the code above ? I have Resource.h but what should I do with it?
Can I edit my resource text file too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assumptions:

- The resource type is "TEXT"
- The resource ID is MY_RESOURCE_ID (this would be a constant from your resource.h)
- You have stored the hInstance for your EXE or DLL (whichever contains the resource) into m_hInstance.

Loading a resource into memory and getting a pointer to it is done like this:

```
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_RESOURCE_ID), L"TEXT");

if (hResource)
{
    HGLOBAL hLoadedResource = LoadResource(m_hInstance, hResource);

    if (hLoadedResource)
    {
        LPVOID pLockedResource = LockResource(hLoadedResource);

        if (pLockedResource)
        {
            DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(m_hInstance, hResource);

            if (0 != dwResourceSize)
            {
                 // Use pLockedResource and dwResourceSize however you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You do not have to unload or unlock the resource on 32-bit or 64-bit vesions of Windows, and if you obtain the resource again you will not leak memory; you always get the same piece of memory.

For updating a resource, see [Updating Resources in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I'm using ATL so I put `_AtlBaseModule.m_hInst` in `hInstance` place and it's working well.
I wonder how to use this chunk of memory like a file or a stream.
If you know please answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346240/

Comment: @CichyK24 stream as in IStream or a different kind of stream?

Comment: Oh, like an ifstream; don't know that, sorry.

Comment: Hello again! I have small [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5065457/350384) about updating resources. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Dear Leo ,How would i get the name of fileName inside the C++ code , in similar situation?