# how to Working with data in memory like a file?

Tags: c++, file, memory, istream

I loaded an entire audio file into memory. Now I need to read from different offsets, in different amounts, with various callbacks.

Is it possible to use the data in memory as in std::istream?

memFile.read, memfile.seekg, memFile.telgq...

Let's say I have something like:

```cpp
size_t dataSize = fileLenght; // for example 5672 
char *fullData = new char[dataSize];
// copy data to fullData...
```

Then I want to do something like:

```cpp
std::istream / fstream / ifstream dataObj(fullData);

dataObj.seekq(0, begin);
dataObj.read(....);
```

These are pseudo code. Things can be different.

I have the start position, end position and length of the file loaded into memory.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

With a basic search the following answer solved my problem. I've done research with complex sentences before. Sorry for the inconvenience.
I am new to C++ and there are many methods, many different approaches in this language.

[How can I read from memory just like from a file using iostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346240/how-can-i-read-from-memory-just-like-from-a-file-using-iostream)