# Inserting a PDF file as a resource, and displaying the pages?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using Visual C++, MFC, and would like to:
(a) Load a pdf file as a resource
(b) Display this file, and be able to move through the pdf file.

The reason why I would like to load the pdf as a resource, is that I do not want the User to be able to download the pdf file (at least not easily).

Can someone please help me?

All the best
Alex

Comment: Would you like to display the PDF file with an external PDF viewer (eg. Adobe Reader) or would you like to display the PDF file by your own ?

Comment: As a work around use a RTF-Control and display the contents here.

Comment: Hi Michael, I would like display the PDF file in a CFormView window. Page forward/ back I would like to use my own buttons. To prevent the user copying the pdf, I would like to have it in resources and compiled into the executable. Thank you Alex

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ActiveX to accomplish what you want.  Adding a custom binary resource to the resource file should be sufficient.  This had been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240188/how-to-load-a-custom-binary-resource-in-a-vc-static-library-as-part-of-a-dll) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344486/how-to-load-text-file-from-resources-in-vc).

Comment: This is only half the answer though. And it really isn't even half since it's just a link to the real answer.

Comment: Hi rrirower

Thank you for your answer.

My new questions then are: If I add the pdf file as a custom binary resource, it will be compiled into the executable- is this right? Can I then display the pdf file using ActiveX? I would like to display the pdf in FormView with my own "Next Page" "Previous Page" etc buttons.

I appreciate all your help.

All the best Alex

Comment: I'm not familiar with those ActiveX controls, but, I would assume that once you stream the contents of the pdf file that is bound to the executable into an external file, you should be able to import it into the control.  I would be surprised if those controls did not expose a method to accomplish that.  Additionally, if you take this approach, you will probably want to delete the pdf file after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are a couple of PDF OCX/ActiveX controls that allow you to view PDF files.

From Adobe itself there is an ActiveX COM Control. You should be able to add it into your toolbox and to drag it on a MFC dialog.

Also I found an older article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9537/Adobe-ActiveX-Control-with-MFC)